# Как связть в выборке один из ManyToMany в QuerySet

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте.

Использую [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities).

Задача: При выборке городов, получить одно из альтернативных имён, исходя из текущего `LANGUAGE_CODE`

вот метод в классе:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        return City.objects.none()

    qs = City.objects.prefetch_related('alt_names').all()

    if self.q:

        qs = qs.filter(alt_names__name__istartswith=self.q, alt_names__language_code=self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)

    return qs
```

Но так, вместе с QuerySet я получаю кучу связанных объектов. То есть, я могу получить название города на нужном языке так:

```
qs[0].alt_names.filter(language_code=self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)[0]
```

Можно ещё сделать так:

```
City.objects.get(name='Vancouver', country__code='CA').alt_names.filter(language_code='ru')
```

Но здесь, опять таки, по отношению к отдельному объекту.

Но, как провернуть эту операцию, по отношению ко всему `QuerySet`? На выходе я хочу получить `QuerySet` городов на нужном языке.

Но проблема ещё заключается в том, что сам по себе `__str__` модели `City` возвращает `self.name`, который на оригинальном языке.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что чуть ли не единственным выходом, будет выбирать из `AlternativeName` названия нужных городов, и показывать именно эти названия, а уже при сохранении формы, заново выбирать города исходя из этих `AlternativeName` ?

Comment: Самым правильным было бы сделать набор таблиц с названиями "language_code" и ForeignKey на "базовое" название, с ними уже работать при необходимости. Меньше будет кушать памяти, и самое главное работать быстрее. Относительно __str__ модели можно ее переопределить, и выбирать нужное значение например по language_code , забранного из request.META например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, решил добавить метод `__str__` у модели City:

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.alt_names.filter(language_code=get_language()).count() > 1:
        return ', '.join([i.name for i in self.alt_names.filter(language_code=get_language()).all()])
    else:
        return self.alt_names.filter(language_code=get_language()).first().name
```

И теперь такой класс во `views.py` даёт то, что нужно:

```
class CityAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return City.objects.none()

        qs = City.objects.prefetch_related('alt_names').all()

        if self.q:

            qs = qs.filter(alt_names__name__istartswith=self.q, alt_names__language_code=self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)[:10]

        return qs
```

Если кому-то будет нужно, то [здесь](https://github.com/narnikgamarnikus/django-cities) форк основного приложения, где метод уже реализован.